# MariaDB Insert queries stuck frequently

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, locking

I am currently doing high insertions into my MariaDB 10.4.12 database via scripts.

However, sometimes the insertion queries just get stuck/piled up at what it seems to be at the `Update` or `Commit` state.

[image: Queries getting stuck]

The above insertions that I am mostly doing (95% of the time) are `INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 ('b1','c1','a1') VALUES (?,?,?)`

Sometimes, they can even go up to 300+ seconds, until eventually all the insertions queries slowly get cleared up within 5-10 seconds (it seems like something is stuck)

I have thought of few things to improve the insert operations :

1. Do BULK insertions instead of many single insertions
2. Use transactions
3. Increase `innodb_log_file_size`

However, ontop of doing that, I would like to know if this is due to other reasons.

When I checked my `iotop` , half of the time it shows that `mysqld` is having `99.99%` I/O

I am not sure if the disks are failing (2TB x4 in mirror setup) or is there some configuration settings that I did not tuned properly?

Table schema :

```
table1 (
  a1 bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  b1 char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  c1 bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  d1 datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  e1 tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  f1 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  LastUpdate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (a1),
  UNIQUE KEY idxc1b1 (c1,b1)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

my.cnf :

```
[mysqld]
symbolic-links=0

innodb_thread_concurrency=32
innodb_buffer_pool_size=240G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=64
innodb_page_cleaners=32
innodb_purge_threads=1
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_use_native_aio=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_doublewrite=0
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_file_per_table=1

max_connections=10000
skip_name_resolve=1
tmp_table_size=134217728
max_heap_table_size=134217728
back_log=1000
wait_timeout=900
innodb_log_buffer_size=32M
innodb_log_file_size=768M
open_files_limit=1024000
max_allowed_packet=512M
```

Update #1 : Added `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` during queries piled up (stuck for 120s+)

GLOBAL STATUS : https://justpaste.it/3hxey

INNODB STATUS : https://justpaste.it/5uren

Update #2 : Added `SHOW VARIABLES`

SHOW VARIABLES : https://justpaste.it/3chha

Update #3 : After replacing the disks (which are also SSDs), the issue is solved. This means that choosing the right SSD disk model is very important for a database high insertion/write rate

Comment: check thr error log, if soemthin is a miss, it will appear there. second i don't now how much rows you have but for every new row, mnysl has to check all constraints

Comment: Why innodb_use_native_aio=0? A higher value of innodb_purge_threads might help too. innodb_log_buffer_size could be increase as could innodb_log_files_in_group/innodb_log_file_size. Drop innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct down to say 25%. Can you include a `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` text/link? Principles of [insert optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html) and [Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) also applly.

Comment: @danblack i updated the post with `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` during the queries piles up. the reason why I used `innodb_use_native_aio=0` and it is stated to help with heavily I/O-bounded systems (not sure how it helps exactly). if I adjust `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct ` to 25%, wouldnt there be more flushing of the disks?

Comment: The `STATUS` values are not very useful without `SHOW  VARIABLES`, too.

Comment: innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct was aimed at decreasing the history size therefore processing/locking time. From your status each pool only has 2-4% of dirty pages. Opened_files is a touch high, not alarmingly given the uptime, but I'm missing the cause. I totally agree with @Rick James's answer below, use a faster insert operation and see what it looks like after that.

Comment: @RickJames i have updated with `SHOW VARIABLES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis of STATUS and VARIABLES**

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.4.12-MariaDB
- 256 GB of RAM  -- Is this correct??
- Uptime = 52d 15:16:00
- Are you sure this was a SHOW GLOBAL STATUS ?
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

Increase `innodb_io_capacity` to 500.

Lower `innodb_lru_scan_depth` to 64

Why?:  `innodb_change_buffering = none`  Normally it is a good feature.

Lots of active threads; was the server melting down as you ran `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`?

Com_admin_commands is huge!  What admin commands are you doing?  Possibly something right before or right after each `INSERT`?  (About 300/sec for each)

80 queries per minute are taking more than 10 seconds.  Turn on the slowlog, etc.

Are you using Galera?

**Details and other observations:**

`( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) = (0 + 0 + 273050 + 951182390 + 0 + 951175516) / 4547760 = 418 /sec` -- IOPs?
-- If the hardware can handle it, set innodb_io_capacity (now 200) to about this value.

`( ( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) / innodb_io_capacity / Uptime ) = ( 0 + 0 + 273050 + 951182390 + 0 + 951175516 ) / 200 / 4547760 = 209.2%` -- This *may* be a metric indicating what innodb_io_capacity is set reasonably.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the hardware can handle it.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 64` -- For large RAM, consider using 1-16 buffer pool instances, not allowing less than 1GB each. Also, not more than, say, twice the number of CPU cores.
-- Recommend no more than 16.

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 1,024 * 64 = 65,536` -- A metric of CPU usage.
-- Lower either number.

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 1,024 * 32 = 32,768` -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners (now 32). Also check for swapping.

`( innodb_page_cleaners / innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 32 / 64 = 0.5` -- innodb_page_cleaners
-- Recommend setting innodb_page_cleaners (now 32) to innodb_buffer_pool_instances (now 64)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( innodb_io_capacity_max / innodb_io_capacity ) = 2,000 / 200 = 10` -- Capacity: max/plain
-- Recommend 2. Max should be about equal to the IOPs your I/O subsystem can handle. (If the drive type is unknown 2000/200 may be a reasonable pair.)

`( (Innodb_buffer_pool_reads + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed) ) = ((242249 + 951175516) ) / 4547760 = 209 /sec` -- InnoDB I/O
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 257698037760)?

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) = 951,175,516 / 4547760 = 209 /sec` -- Writes (flushes)
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 257698037760)?

`( innodb_change_buffering ) = innodb_change_buffering = none`
-- Pre-5.6.11 / 5.5.31, there was a bug that made ="changes" a safer option.

`( innodb_doublewrite ) = innodb_doublewrite = OFF` -- Extra I/O, but extra safety in crash.
-- OFF is OK for FusionIO, Galera, Slaves, ZFS.

`( Innodb_os_log_written ) = 1,867,005,211,648 / 4547760 = 410532 /sec` -- This is an indicator of how busy InnoDB is.
-- Very idle or very busy InnoDB.

`( Innodb_log_writes ) = 1,029,874,951 / 4547760 = 226 /sec`

`( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method = fsync` -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT

`( default_tmp_storage_engine ) = default_tmp_storage_engine =`

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( ( Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written ) / Uptime / innodb_io_capacity ) = ( 273050 + 951182390 ) / 4547760 / 200 = 104.6%` -- If > 100%, need more io_capacity.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the drives can handle it.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( max_connections ) = 15,934` -- Maximum number of connections (threads). Impacts various allocations.
-- If max_connections (now 15934) is too high and various memory settings are high, you could run out of RAM.

`( character_set_server ) = character_set_server = latin1`
-- Charset problems may be helped by setting character_set_server (now latin1) to utf8mb4. That is the future default.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( tmp_table_size ) = 128M` -- Limit on size of *MEMORY* temp tables used to support a SELECT
-- Decrease tmp_table_size (now 134217728) to avoid running out of RAM. Perhaps no more than 64M.

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (1371247297 + 4324897 + 1 + 0) / 1 = 1.38e+9` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Select_full_join / Com_select ) = 3,469 / 49002 = 7.1%` -- % of selects that are indexless join
-- Add suitable index(es) to tables used in JOINs.

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 83,957 / 49002 = 171.3%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) = (1371247297 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 4324897 + 0) / 4547760 = 302 /sec` -- writes/sec
-- 50 writes/sec + log flushes will probably max out I/O write capacity of normal drives

`( Com_admin_commands ) = 1,350,052,920 / 4547760 = 296 /sec`
-- Why so many DDL statements?

`( Com_admin_commands / Queries ) = 1,350,052,920 / 1387441904 = 97.3%` -- Percent of queries that are "admin" commands.
-- What's going on?

`( Com_set_option / Com_select ) = 3,505,412 / 49002 = 7153.6%`
-- It seems 'wrong' to do more SETs than SELECTs.

`( Com__biggest ) = Com__biggest = Com_insert` -- Which of the "Com_" metrics is biggest.
-- Normally it is Com_select (now 49002). If something else, then it may be a sloppy platform, or may be something else.

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Slow_queries ) = 5,897,189 / 4547760 = 1.3 /sec` -- Frequency (Slow queries per sec)
-- Rework slow guys; improve indexes; watch disk space for slow log file

`( Max_used_connections ) = 597` -- High-water mark for connections
-- Lots of inactive connections is OK; over 100 active connections is likely to be a problem. Max_used_connections (now 597) does not distinguish them; Threads_running (now 299) is instantaneous.

`( Threads_running - 1 ) = 299 - 1 = 298` -- Active threads (concurrency when data collected)
-- Optimize queries and/or schema

`( thread_pool_size ) = 40` -- Number of 'thread groups'. Limits how many treads can be executing at once. Probably should not be much bigger than the number of CPUs.
-- Don't set much higher than the number of CPU cores.

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

**Abnormally small:**

```
(Com_select + Qcache_hits) / (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) = 3.6e-5
Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused = 15,687
Com_select = 39 /HR
Created_tmp_files = 0.0032 /HR
Empty_queries = 14 /HR
Handler_icp_attempts = 0.0024 /HR
Handler_icp_match = 0.0024 /HR
Handler_read_first = 0.066 /HR
Handler_read_rnd = 0.0071 /HR
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads * innodb_page_size / innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1.5%
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written = 0
Innodb_num_open_files = 6
Memory_used = 0.13%
Select_range = 0.0063 /HR
Sort_priority_queue_sorts = 0
Sort_rows = 0.078 /HR
Sort_scan = 0.013 /HR
innodb_spin_wait_delay = 4
lock_wait_timeout = 86,400
table_open_cache / max_connections = 0.126
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_do = 0.0024 /HR
Com_insert = 301 /sec
Feature_json = 0.07 /sec
Handler_discover = 0.041 /HR
Handler_read_next / Handler_read_key = 100
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data = 1.53e+7
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty = 410,202
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / max(Questions, Queries) = 0.686
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total = 1.54e+7
Innodb_data_pending_writes = 32
Innodb_data_writes = 435 /sec
Innodb_data_writes - Innodb_log_writes - Innodb_dblwr_writes = 209 /sec
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs = 1
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes = 1
Innodb_pages_written = 209 /sec
Threads_connected = 304
Threads_running = 299
histogram_size = 254
host_cache_size = 1,103
innodb_page_cleaners = 32
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 32
innodb_thread_sleep_delay = 48,937
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
max_long_data_size = 512MB
max_relay_log_size = 1024MB
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 4
performance_schema_max_cond_classes = 90
performance_schema_max_stage_classes = 160
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
aria_recover_options = BACKUP,QUICK
disconnect_on_expired_password = OFF
ft_boolean_syntax = + -><()~*:\"\"&
histogram_type = DOUBLE_PREC_HB
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_use_atomic_writes = ON
innodb_use_native_aio = OFF
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
myisam_stats_method = NULLS_UNEQUAL
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
opt_s__optimize_join_buffer_size = on
optimizer_trace = enabled=off
plugin_maturity = gamma
sql_safe_updates = ON
use_stat_tables = PREFERABLY_FOR_QUERIES
wsrep_data_home_dir = /data01/mysql/
wsrep_debug = NONE
wsrep_load_data_splitting = OFF
```

Comment: thanks for  the huge analysis rick! i have adjusted my scripts to do BULK insertions instead and it is definitely faster. i also have adjusted `innodb_io_capacity` to 500, `innodb_lru_scan_depth` to 100 (minimum is 100) and ` innodb_change_buffering` back to all. the server is not running Galera yet. the `com_admin_commands` is exceedingly high due to the script pinging the database server before every insertion - i have since removed that (thanks for pointing out).

Comment: now, the queries still get stuck, but not as often. however, there are still times where 1 single bulk insertion (100 records at once) can take up to a staggering 90 seconds. i am suspecting it is actually due to disks the server have - are there any ways I can rule this out?

Comment: Issue is solved after replacing the SSD disks with a newer SSD disk model. I guess the previous SSD model had lousy write rate

Answer (score 0):

[very good] Do BULK insertions instead of many single insertions -- Yes.  Inserting 100 rows in a single `INSERT` can run 10 times as fast.

[good] Use transactions -- Multiple single-row `INSERTs` save some by doing this.

[it depends] Increase innodb_log_file_size -- There are metrics in `GLOBAL STATUS` that would help determine the utility of this.  (Your 768M is probably big enough.)

[minor] char(64) -- Is it truly fixed length?  If not, use `VARCHAR`.  If it is just ascii, then say so.  If it is hex, then consider using `UNHEX()` and putting it into `BINARY(32)`.  Shrinking the size of the table always helps, but usually by only a small amount.

[safety] max_connections=10000 -- Shrink to something reasonable.  If you ever hit 10000, the system would (1) really bog down, and (2) swap, which would be terrible for performance.

[?] innodb_buffer_pool_size=240G -- This implies that you have at least 300GB of RAM?  How big is (or will be) the table?

[RAID] 4 drives just Mirrored?  No striping?  Hardware (better) vs software controller?

[2 unique keys] Each row must check both before committing.  Is the `CHAR(64)` a hash of some kind -- hence "random"?

[stumbling] If you have too many clients, they will just stumble over each other.  Your image show a rather long list.  (I don't have a good number for where InnoDB stops improving and starts stumbling.  But it sounds like you have too many.)

The first item will probably be the most productive.  But we can discuss the rest.

Comment: i have updated the post with `GLOBAL STATUS` and `ENGINE INNODB STATUS` during the queries pile up. for char(64) - yes it is fixed 64 character. regarding the table size, it can potentially go up to 2-3 TB. for raid, i am actually using ZFS mirror setup for 4 x 2TB (effectively 2 disks being used)